# Выделять только полные слова

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция которая находит на странице слова которые есть в массиве и заключает их в тег.

Она работает хорошо, но проблема в том что она заключает в тег даже часть слова, например, если в массиве есть:

> "кот", "собака"

а текст такой:

> ... тот который ...

то получится так:

```
... тот <span class="highlight">кот</span>орый ...
```

Нужно чтобы функция выделяла только полные слова.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```js
var words = ["кот", "текст", "пример"];

highlight(document.body, words);


function highlight(elem, keywords, caseSensitive = false, cls = 'highlight') {
        const flags = caseSensitive ? 'gi' : 'g';
        keywords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
        Array.from(elem.childNodes).forEach(child => {
            const keywordRegex = RegExp(keywords.join('|'), flags);
            if (child.nodeType !== 3) { // not a text node
                highlight(child, keywords, caseSensitive, cls);
            } else if (keywordRegex.test(child.textContent)) {
                const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                let lastIdx = 0;
                child.textContent.replace(keywordRegex, (match, idx) => {
                    const part = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx, idx));
                    const highlighted = document.createElement('span');
                    highlighted.textContent = match;
                    highlighted.classList.add(cls);
                    frag.appendChild(part);
                    frag.appendChild(highlighted);
                    lastIdx = idx + match.length;
                });
                const end = document.createTextNode(child.textContent.slice(lastIdx));
                frag.appendChild(end);
                child.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, child);
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<body>
пример текста который стоит тут
</body>
```

Comment: child.textContent.split(" ") и сравнивайте через перебор полученного массива

Comment: @BearVorkuta не могли бы, пожалуйста, внести изменения в код который я привел выше?

Comment: Я чуть сократил, уж простите.

Answer (score 3):

```js
  const words = ["кот", "текст", "пример"];

highlight(document.body, words);

function highlight(elem, keywords, cls = 'highlight') {        
   Array.from(elem.childNodes).forEach(child => {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {                      
     let html = [];
     let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
     child.textContent.trim().split(" ").forEach(word => {              
       if (keywords.some(el => { return el == word })) {            
          const highlighted = document.createElement('span');
          highlighted.innerHTML = ` <span class='${cls}'>${word}</span> `
          frag.appendChild(highlighted)                            
       } else {
        const part = document.createTextNode(` ${word} `);            
        frag.appendChild(part)               
       }
     });              
     child.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, child);    
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<body>
пример текста который стоит тут, а кот гуляет
</body>
```

Comment: а почему у вас выделяет тут слова? ведь в массиве нет слов которые есть в тексте)

Comment: @iKey поправил код

Comment: здесь в примере срабатывает как надо, а вот на сайте ошибка: `words is not defined`. там у вас `words` объявлена const вне функции, а надо именно в функцию передавать слова. я попробовал заменить, но что-то не выходит у меня(( буду очень благодарен вам

Comment: @iKey мой косяк, исправил

Comment: опять же, здесь в примере работает отлично, а на сайте теперь просто пропадает весь body :( простите что вас так замучил этим, сам не особо покуда разбираюсь в javascript

Answer (score 3):

С исправленной регуляркой, и упрощенным созданием фрагмента документа (неявным - через присваивание `outerHTML`):

```js
var words = ["кот", "текст", "пример"];

highlight(document.body, words);


function highlight(elem, keywords, caseSensitive = false, cls = 'highlight') {
  const flags = caseSensitive ? 'giu' : 'gu';
  const keywordRegex = RegExp(`(\\P{L})(${keywords.join('|')})(\\P{L})`, flags);
  keywords.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  Array.from(elem.childNodes).forEach(child => {
    if (child.nodeType !== 3) { // not a text node
      highlight(child, keywords, caseSensitive, cls);
    } else {
      const replacement = document.createElement('span');
      child.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, child);
      replacement.outerHTML = child.textContent.replace(keywordRegex,
        `$1<span class="${cls}">$2</span>$3`
      );
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  пример текста который стоит тут как кот
</body>
```

Создание экземпляра `RegExp` поднял, т.к. нет практического смысла на каждой итерации его пересоздавать.

Comment: на сайте выдает ошибку: `Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null`

Comment: @iKey, мои соболезнования сайту и его кривеньким event handler'ам. В примере из вопроса нет обработчиков событий, соотв. и в ответе тоже.