# Как получить NodeList созданных элементов через JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно доступиться до конкретного элемента в NodeList-e, и при нажатии на него удалить из таблицы строку (а также удалить из массива сам объект), но не могу получить доступ до кнопки из списка.

у меня есть :

```
<tbody id="user-list"></tbody>

let list = document.getElementById('user-list'); // доступ

function AddUser() { // create user
    let obj = {};
    obj.name = loginField.value; // собирает из инпутов value и формирует объект
    obj.pass = passField.value; // собирает из инпутов value и формирует объект
    obj.mail = mailField.value; // собирает из инпутов value и формирует объект
    arr.push(obj); пушит в массив
    loginField.value = '';
    passField.value = '';
    mailField.value = '';
}
```

Этот объект нужно "рендерить" в html -

```
function render() {

    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        row.innerHTML = `
        <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>${arr[i].name}</td>
        <td>${arr[i].pass}</td>
        <td>${arr[i].mail}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning edit">Edit</button></td> // бутстрап кнопка
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button></td> // бутстрап кнопка
        `;
    }
    list.append(row);
}
```

Как мне получить доступ ко всем созданным кнопкам, чтобы потом удалить из массива этот объект по индексу? NodeList всегда пустой, он не видит кнопок и даже строк или ячеек в таблице (через `querySelectorAll()`)

Comment: "NodeList всегда пустой, он не видит кнопок и даже строк или ячеек в таблице (через querySelectorAll())" - я пробовал, tr он видит ибо вы создали узел tr. Более того, и NodeList с td он возвращает непустой.(но это после выполнения функций AddUser() и render() ибо какой смысл обращаться к тому, чего нет)

Comment: Также неясно зачем вы делаете именно такую цепочку путешествия информации. Т.е вы взяли данные с инпутов, ок. Затем вы эти данные записали в свойства объекта, ок. Потом добавили этот объект в массив, потом обратились к элементу этого массива и только потом отрендерели нужный элемент. Может я чего-то не понимаю, но кто-нибудь может объяснить зачем? Почему бы на этапе создания объекта не создавать сразу tr и кнопки путем метода этого объекта? (это вопрос к тем, кто понимает, я не понимаю).

Comment: @freestyle_HD, да в принципе незачем, ты прав в том что задачу можно решить гораздо меньшим количеством шагов. Но ТС похоже не очень умеет работать с DOM (достаточно взглянуть на `innerHTML`), и не очень много внимания уделил постижению основ программинга (и структурам данных в частности) - поэтому делает как умеет, вот и все. Сейчас практически нормой является ситуация когда конечный продукт ставится выше получения навыков, и обучают в соответствии с этой системой ценностей.

Comment: @yar85, я лишь увидел интересный вопрос и поинтересовался т.к. у меня практически нет практического опыта в js, а теорию еще учить и учить. По поводу innerHTML не понял, что там не так, может проясните хотя бы в 2-ух словах?

Comment: @freestyle_HD, в данном случае, прием с `innerHTML` менее удобен и читаем, чем стандартные DOM-методы вставки столбцов и ячеек таблицы. Плюс, сама по себе практика присваивания `innerHTML` считается плохой, по ряду причин... например, она может открыть уязвимость (из-за чего присваивание этому свойству напрочь блокируется на современных страницах с CSP), может сломать разметку документа (что при работе с объектами элементов исключено), да и просто потому что зачастую `innerHTML` используется не по назначению (например, для изменения текстового содержимого).

Comment: @freestyle_HD, ну и, когда требуется работа именно с разметкой, для ее вставки уже давно есть более эффективный метод `insertAdjacentHTML` - который хоть и тоже небезопасен, но зато более гибок и вызывает меньше негативных побочных эффектов (как минимум, более стоек к ошибкам т.к. вставляемый фрагмент парсится отдельно, и этот метод снижает количество reflow документа на самой вставке, по сравнению с "пещерным" прямым присваиванием куска разметки).

Comment: @yar85, интересно, а если бы у него была там не таблица, а многострочный кусок HTML кода и стояла бы задача внедрить кусок HTML-кода, я так понимаю, для вложенных элементов лучше использовать .createElement для каждого узла или лучше создать объект и потом уже на основе его генерировать html-структуру? или это не то и нужно как-то иначе?

Comment: @freestyle_HD, если говорить в общем, то работа с объектами DOM конечно предпочтительнее работы с разметкой: первое и значительно надежнее/безопаснее, и позволяет оптимизации (если те потребуются), и упрощает комплексные задачи (когда с создаваемыми элементами надо выполнить несколько действий). Помимо `createElement` есть великое множество разных методов, в DOM вообще весьма богатый функционал... и сказать "используй только это всегда" не получится - задачи ведь разные бывают, поэтому надо смотреть в первую очередь на алгоритм, чтобы выбрать наиболее подходящие к решению инструменты DOM.

Comment: @freestyle_HD, еще я возможно неточно выразился - сама по себе работа с разметкой _бывает_ оправдана задачей. Просто ее весьма часто используют для всего (не глядя на более разумные альтернативы), и именно такое бездумное применение создает плохие практики (а сам `innerHTML` ни в чем не виноват, и по назначению такие вещи использовать вполне нормально). Вот приведу пример задачи, где надо обернуть часть текстового нода в элемент - [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305147/288409) я использовал трюк с `outerHTML`, что избавило реализацию (см. в вопросе) от усложнения вычислениями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Две функции (для рендеринга элементов данных, и для делегированной обработки кликов по кнопкам), с их использованием:

```js
function render(items, tBody, fields = []) {
  const buf = document.createElement('tbody');
  for (const item of items) {
    const row = buf.insertRow();
    fields.forEach(fld => row.insertCell().textContent = item[fld]);
    // на самом деле, кнопки было бы лучше рендерить тоже из объекта-конфига действий (операций над элементом данных), но для простоты пусть разметкой
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning edit">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button></td>
    `);
    row._item = item;  // сохраняем в DOM-объекте ссылку на соотв. объект данных
  }
  tBody.replaceChildren(...buf.children);
  return tBody.children;  // если и правда нужен NodeList строк таблицы...
}

function clickHandler(items, renderFunc, evt) {
  const btn = evt.target.closest('.btn');
  if (!btn) return;
  const item = btn.closest('tr')._item;
  if (btn.classList.contains('edit')) {
    console.log('edit item', item);  // тут предполагается заполнение формы значениями из `item`
  } else if (btn.classList.contains('delete')) {
    const itemIdx = items.indexOf(item);
    if (itemIdx > -1) {
      items.splice(itemIdx, 1);
      console.log('item deleted\n', items);
      renderFunc();
    }
  }
}

const users = [
  { name: 'Василий', passw: 'dgh384fgy8', email: 'pupkin@example.com' },
  { name: 'Иван', passw: 'танки7777', email: 'vanyalolpro@example.com' },
  { name: 'Екатерина', passw: '1234', email: 'kitty@example.com' },
  { name: 'Петр', passw: 'j56fg646t3', email: 'pt@example.com' },
  { name: 'Анастасия', passw: '04101995', email: 'support@example.com' },
];
const tBody = document.querySelector('table tbody'),
      userFields = ['name', 'passw', 'email'],
      renderUsers = render.bind(this, users, tBody, userFields),
      usersClickHandler = clickHandler.bind(tBody, users, renderUsers);
tBody.addEventListener('click', usersClickHandler);  // общий обработчик кликов по элементам таблицы - тут используется только для кнопок
renderUsers();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0.2em 0.3em; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Рекомендую после запуска примера нажать "На всю страницу", чтобы консольный вывод не мешал видеть таблицу.

---

Функция `render` в примере возвращает `NodeList` состоящий из элементов `tr`, но в данном случае это никак не используется - сделано только чтобы ответить на одну из частей заданного вопроса (чтобы показать как это в принципе можно реализовать).

*// Вообще, тут разумнее было бы применить ООП, сделав эти функции методами объекта данных (или разделив на объекты модели и контроллера), но раз вопрос
с отдельными самостоятельными функциями, то и ответ соответственно с такими же.*

Answer (score 1):

В конец функции render попробуйте добавить:

```
list.querySelectorAll('tr .btn.remove').forEach((elem,index) => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(){                  
        arr.splice(index,1)
        render()
    })      
})
```

И если Вы хотите отрисовывать таблицу заново, возможно лучше очищать содержимое, а потом аппендить.

```
list.innerHTML = ''
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ )